# Setting up a vector representation

Tags: vectors

I'm having some trouble setting up vector representations. I was given the following question:

> Given are the points $A(1,-3)$, $B(4,2)$ and $C(-2,1)$. Set up the vector representation for the line $k$ through point $B$, which is parallel to $AC$.

After drawing the points, I had no idea where to start. I did the following:

$\overrightarrow{AC}=\bigg(\begin{array}{c}
      -3 \\
      4
    \end{array}\bigg)$ and $\overrightarrow{CB}=\bigg(\begin{array}{c}
      6 \\
      1
    \end{array}\bigg)$. Let's say that $\overrightarrow{AC}=:\overline{q}$ and $\overrightarrow{CB}=:\overline{r}$. I first thought that the answer was:

$k: \bigg(\begin{array}{c}
      x \\
      y
    \end{array}\bigg)=\overline{r}+\lambda\overline{q}$  with $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Is this correct or did I make a mistake?

Comment: This is correct. Note that $\overrightarrow{AC} = \overrightarrow{C}-\overrightarrow{A}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made one mistake:

You can't use $\overrightarrow{CB}$ as a position vector on the line, since $C$ 
doesn't lie on $k$ (since $\overrightarrow{AC}\parallel k$).

---

A vector equation is

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}-3\\4\end{pmatrix}$$

Since the line is parallel to $\overrightarrow{AC}$, we can use $\overrightarrow{AC}$ as a direction vector.

As a position vector, we can use $\overrightarrow{OB}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot that I can't use $\overrightarrow{CB}$ as position.